# Get anchor element ID with javascript in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to return the ID of an anchor tag in javascript in Django, however for some reason it always returns "undefined".

HTML:

```
<div class="list-group">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Select Drug</a>
{% for drug in drugs %}
<a id="TESTING" href="javascript:AddToList()" class="list-group-item drugName">
{{ drug }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function AddToList() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is top pass the `this`, reference to the element which invoke the event to the event handler `AddToList`. Then event handler just fetch the `id` property from element.

*HTML*

```
<a id="TESTING" href="javascript:AddToList(this)" class="list-group-item drugName">
```

*Script*

```
function AddToList(elem) {
   alert(elem.id);
}
```

---

Since you are using jQuery, I would recommend you to bind event handler using it

*HTML*

```
<a id="TESTING" class="list-group-item drugName">
```

*Script*

```
function AddToList() {
   alert(this.id);
}

//DOM Ready handler
$(function(){
    //Use class selector to bind event handler
    $('.drugName').on('click', AddToList)

    //Or, Use ID selector to bind event handler
    $('#TESTING').on('click', AddToList)
});
```

Comment: in your second AddToList function you should use `this` instead of argument because that will be an event.